# What is the best way to inverse sort a list with this date format?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a database with million of records like this:

```
[("Something", "10/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
("Something", "16/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
("Something", "14/07/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
("Something", "14/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
("Something", "15/07/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
("Something", "14/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc")]
```

That's DD/MM/YYYY And I need it sorted reversed by the 2nd value.

**First attempt:**
I tried this but it sorts only by the day, not by month.

```
def sort_by(my_list, index):
    my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[index], reverse=True)
    return my_list
```

Picture of the result (ignore the colors, it's from my GUI): https://image.prntscr.com/image/ZeIgzxNaQ2OD4VX0Yztnhw.png
As you can see it sorts it only by the day, but not by month, so it keeps jumping from one month to another each time the day changes. That's a total mess.

**Second attempt:**

```
def sort_by_date(my_list, index):
    for record, data in enumerate(my_list):
        split = data[index].split("/")
        altered_record = my_list[record]
        altered_record[index] = split[2]+"-"+split[1]+"-"+split[0]
    my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[index], reverse=True)
    return my_list
```

And by that time I realized it won't work because tuples doesn't allow item assignment, so I'd have to transform the entire data into a list of lists instead of a list of tuples. And even if I do that I doubt it's efficient and it will take a lot of time to do the job.

**So my question is:**
How would you sort a list of tuples by DD/MM/YYYY?

As per comment from @juanpa.arrivillaga, the desired output is a reversed sorted list by date:

```
31/12/2017
30/12/2017
29/12/2017
28/12/2017
(And the next days of that month)
30/11/2017
29/11/2017
28/11/2017
27/11/2017
(And so go on)
```

**Edit:** If possible I want to keep the date as a string, not changing the date type.

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* what you are looking for (as in produce the corresponding output from your example input)?

Comment: Also, you say you want to keep the date as a string, and yet, you want to *treat* it as a date... why?

Comment: Desired output added. And I want to keep the result as a string to easily display it on my GUI, as it's easier to just show an string than transforming it from a date every single time. That though might be a noob movement as I'm still learning python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Python's `datetime` module for this:

```
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

database = [("Something", "10/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
            ("Something", "16/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
            ("Something", "14/07/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
            ("Something", "14/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
            ("Something", "15/07/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc"),
            ("Something", "14/08/2017", "something else", "something more", "etc")]

pprint(sorted(database, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=True))
```

Which has output:

```
[('Something', '16/08/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc'),
 ('Something', '14/08/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc'),
 ('Something', '14/08/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc'),
 ('Something', '10/08/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc'),
 ('Something', '15/07/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc'),
 ('Something', '14/07/2017', 'something else', 'something more', 'etc')]
```

Comment: Tested, it works. Will accept it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the whole database of 1M records in memory, the best solution would be:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda rec: int(rec[1][-4:] + rec[1][3:5] + rec[1][:2]), reverse=True)
```

It is very close to your second solution, except that you do not modify the list at all, but just extract the key of each record on demand. And the key will have the form `20170811` of the integer type for the original `'11/08/2017'` string.

And it does not create the datetime objects, as parsing can be too expensive, when you need it only for sorting.

And it compares even faster than the datetime objects and than the strings. Because the integer comparison is the fastest possible.

And it consumes least memory during sorting, because the integers are the most compact way of storing the keys (relative to the strings & datetimes).

---

It can be even more optimized (for no real benefit, but for fun) by storing the number of days since some base date (compare: `20170811` (20'170'811) vs `736551` (736'551) days since 01.01.0001 or `17389` (17'389) since 01.01.1970). And the computational cost is not so much bigger, compared to the datetime parsing.

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda rec: int(rec[1][-4:])*32*12 + int(rec[1][3:5])*32 + int(rec[1][:2]), reverse=True)
```

Here, we assume that every month is always 32 days, and every year is always 32*12=384 days. Because we do not care about the actual number of days, but only about their relative position on the numeric axis. This covers the cases with 28-29-30-31 days easily.

---

PS: However, if you really have a database of 1M records, I would advise you to sort it in the database server with proper SQL — faster and more optimized. But this is another big topic which depends on how the database is organized.

Comment: It is true that parsing a `datetime` object is more expensive, but `datetime` object comparison (i.e. `<`, `>`, etc.) is faster than string comparison because there is less work to do. Since the comparison is done more than the transformation during sorting it may be worth the up-front cost of the `datetime` conversion for very large data sets.

Comment: @SethMMorton That is true. I've just updated my answer to convert the strings to the ints. Now it is even faster than both the string & datetime objects, because what can be faster than the int comparison? ;-)